# Running `git apply` in the context of a SAPI seems to be impossible

Tags: php, git

I've done A LOT of debugging today to try to figure out why [this](https://github.com/gitonomy/gitlib/issues/209) isn't working.

I'm trying to use a patch file to stage a single hunk of a file diff. This works perfectly fine from the command line and even via PHP from the command line (this suggests it's an environment thing, but trust me, I've been there...).

As soon as I try to run it through a browser/web server, PHP doesn't like it. The command runs, but there's no useful output and the patch doesn't get applied.

I have not been able to get this to work and I can't figure out why... I've been around everything, double-triple-quadruple checking everything and checking it again: environment variables, permissions, paths, even completely starting a new repo in case it got somehow corrupted.

```php
shell_exec("echo '{$patch}' | git --git-dir /path/to/project/.git --work-tree /path/to/project apply --cached -")
```

(You may find it helpful to put the patch in a file)

In summary, take a patch file (e.g. some of the output from a `git diff`) and use `shell_exec` to pipe the patch to `git apply` and see if it works.

Hopefully you'll either see it working and I can continue banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why it doesn't work on my machine, or you'll see what I see, which is no errors, a return code of `0` and no staged hunk.

One good thing: I know a lot more about how git works now

Comment: `$patch` here is a PHP variable. Embedded `'` in your patch make your shell trip (because the string is terminated).

Comment: That's potentially true... perhaps using `echo` isn't the best... I'll update the question to suggest using a patch file and reading it out to the `apply` command

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Use [`chdir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) to make sure you run commands from the root of the repo.

---

So in the process of reformatting my question to provide a more easy-to-reproduce example, I found that my easy to reproduce example actually worked...

Here's how to replicate with a basic repo:

```bash
mkdir php-git-apply
cd php-git-apply
git init
echo "Hello, world" > test.txt
git add . && git commit -m "Init"
echo "Hello, git" > test.txt
git diff test.txt > my.patch

# Then create the PHP script:

echo "<?php
shell_exec('cat my.patch | git apply --cached -');" > apply.php

# And run it - this should work
php apply.php
```

If you can point a web server that will parse PHP at your `/path/to/php-git-apply` and load up `apply.php` in the browser you'll see this actually works. How annoying.

So why doesn't it work in my other project? Well my other project is more complicated and loads via a front controller in `public/index.php`. This means that the default working directory is now `/path/to/ptoject/public` (not `/path/to/project`).

So this suggested that it's got absolutely nothing to do with the SAPI or environment and everything to do with where in the world the commands are being executed from.

Seems pretty obvious.

Sadly, I then went down a dark path of trying to set all the paths I could against `git apply` (`--directory`, `--include` etc) and even changing the paths in the patch file into various configurations - all to no avail.

I also spent a lot of time working out how to debug `git apply` (it's really no forthcoming with any useful output about what's going 'wrong') and using `patch -p1 < ...` etc.

But I was missing an even more obvious trick!

Ultimately it was far easier to simply switch PHP's working directory and execute the commands in that context than trying any of all these fancy/fruitless tricks to convince `git apply` that "it's ok to apply this patch to this file... really... trust me!"

Changing the working directory in PHP is of course super easy with `chdir()`.

Done and done